# How to get the Contact Guids from a PartyList in a Plugin?

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm making a plugin that triggers on the create message of a custom activity SMS.
These plugin will send the actual sms using a third party sms service provider.

Therefore i need to get the mobilephone numbers for every contact in the "To" field of the SMS activity. This is a field of type: PartyList.

I'm currently using the following code:

```
EntityCollection Recipients;
Entity entity = (Entity) context.InputParameters["Target"];

IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

Content = entity.GetAttributeValue<String>("subject");
Recipients = entity.GetAttributeValue<EntityCollection>("to");

for (int i = 0; i < Recipients.Entities.Count; i++)
{
  Entity ent= Recipients[i];

  string number = ent["MobilePhone"].ToString();    
}
```

But this is not working, i think the ent variable contains no attributes.

I've tried coding with ActivityParty also but not luck either.

I hope someone of you can help me with this one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's is how I finally did it:

```
EntityCollection Recipients;
Entity entity = (Entity) context.InputParameters["Target"];

IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory 
  = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(
    typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory)); 
IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory
  .CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId); 

Content = entity.GetAttributeValue<String>("subject"); 
Recipients = entity.GetAttributeValue<EntityCollection>("to"); 

for (int i = 0; i < Recipients.Entities.Count; i++)
{
  ActivityParty ap = Recipients[i].ToEntity<ActivityParty>();
  String contactid = ap.PartyId.Id.ToString();
  Contact c = (Contact) service.Retrieve(
    Contact.EntityLogicalName,
    ap.PartyId.Id,
    new ColumnSet(new string[]{ "mobilephone" }));
  String mobilephone = c.MobilePhone;
  ...
}
```

Comment: I'm using early-bound types in my plugin and fetching an Email's To field was problematic in the same way. Changing the code to late-bound as shown here solved my issue as well.

Answer (score 7):

`Recipients` is a list of [`ActivityParty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328549.aspx), not of contacts, accounts, ... .
Therefore you have to read its [`PartyId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328278.aspx#attribute)

```
EntityReference partyId = ent.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("partyid");
```

With this information you have to look for the record which is referecend with this partyID. It could be a contact, an account, a systemuser, ...
You'll get this information trough

```
var partyType = partyId.LogicalName;
```

Then you could retrieve the record this record in order to read the number.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried using ActivityParty. But it never worked either. What do i have to change in my code? 
1. ActivityParty Recipients; (or ActivityParty[]) ?
2. Recipients = entity.GetAttributeValue<ActivityParty>("to"); (or ActivityParty[]) ?
When i do this, i 'll get a error that i cannot cast EntityCollection into ActivityParty.

When i use the entitycollection type, and cast each object in the collection to an activityparty i get error: "Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity' to type 'ActivityParty'."

What am I still doing wrong?