# Set the Lookup field to show only Contacts

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I have a lookup field which shows a lookup for 4 entities. So, I have added the PreSearch Filter to filter only the contacts when I click on the field.
[image]
But, when I click on **Look for more Records**, I want the search to be made only on Contacts entity.

I want to see only Contacts entity on the following image : [image]

Is it possible?

Comment: Was this resolved?

Answer (score 1):

It’s not possible to hide those related entities from the list. But we can disallow the users to choose any other unwanted entity records in that lookup.

We have to use `addPreSearch` and `addCustomFilter`. For example, to allow users to choose only contact but not account or systemuser, see the following snippet. This will filter out account & systemuser records from the view & users can move forward only by choosing contact.

```
    var contactFilter = "<filter type='and'><condition attribute='contactid' operator='not-null' /></filter>";
    //remove accounts
    var accountFilter = "<filter type='and'><condition attribute='accountid' operator='null' /></filter>";
    //remove system users
    var systemUserFilter = "<filter type='and'><condition attribute='systemuserid' operator='null' /></filter>";
Xrm.Page.getControl('requiredattendees').addCustomFilter(contactFilter, "contact");
Xrm.Page.getControl('requiredattendees').addCustomFilter(accountFilter, "account");    
Xrm.Page.getControl('requiredattendees').addCustomFilter(systemUserFilter, "systemuser");
```

[Read more](http://dynamicscrmcoe.com/custom-filter-lookup/)

**Edit**:

Adding another undocumented (hence unsupported) till 8.x

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute('your_field').setLookupTypes(['contact']);
```

9.x documented & supported way:

```
Xrm.Page.getControl('your_field').setEntityTypes(['contact']);
```

**Update**: (replacement of above deprecated syntax)

```
function onFormLoad(executionContext) {
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext(); 
    formContext.getControl('your_field').setEntityTypes(['contact']);
}
```

[Read more](https://dreamingincrm.com/2016/06/02/restricting-the-customer-lookup/)

Comment: There may be unsupported DOM manipulation to remove the entity list item, which community won’t recommend.

Comment: Are you sure about "Xrm.Page.getControl(“to”).setEntityTypes([“contact”,”lead”,”systemuser”]);"? This is not working.

Comment: @RichaTibrewal sorry, I was answering in mobile & possibly bcoz of fancy double quotes it was not working. I tested now & edited the answer with single quote around field name. :)