# Changing the behavior of the +New button in a party list

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have an existing field that uses partylist that will allow multiple Accounts in one field. However, when selecting on the +New button shown, it shows the quick creation for 'Contact' instead of 'Account'

I am wondering if I can customize the behavior of the +New button

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot change the behavior of + New Button w.r.t Partylist.
Yes you are right by default CRM opens Quick create of contact. I just tried that on my instance for Classic UI (i.e old UI)
[image]

However if you are on Version 9 or above of CRM I would recommned move to new UI. Below is lookup for Appointment entity which is party list. Here you can choose which entity you wish to have a quick create for and then will open a particular entity quick create from.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are not using Contacts but only Accounts as Activity parties in your scenario.

In that case, you can [use `setEntityTypes`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50837293) to control the entity types you want to leverage for that lookup control ie. Activity party. This will regulate the `+ New` button experience for opening Quick create form.

```
function onFormLoad(executionContext) {
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext(); 
    formContext.getControl('requiredattendees').setEntityTypes(['account']);
}
```